# PlayN java desktop version slower than web version?

Tags: java, gwt, playn

so i've been playing with google PlayN, and i built a small sprite sheet loader for explosions.

what is weird thought is that the desktop java version (that uses the same core code) runs way slower than my web version.

for instance my web version: sapropwns.appspot.com (click with left mouse button and drag the pointer), as you can see its pretty smooth. on the other hand the java desktop version lags every like 2 secs and doesnt draw as much as this web version (the trail doesnt have as much drawing even though both use the same mouse callback for drawing at the same speed).

is there a limitation on the PlayN library that im missing?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I've noticed this, too. I'll get flickering on my desktop version where web version is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I looked at PlayN (I was poking at it for a little while for fun).  But performance for desktop apps may not be great for certain applications since they are using straight-up Java2D for their rendering.  I'm also guessing it's not all that optimized at this point.

There is some [discussion on the PlayN group](http://groups.google.com/group/playn/browse_thread/thread/d2c7367b6d4c4b07#) about improving performance by switching from Java2D to [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) (Lightweight Java Game Library).  This would improve performance greatly for desktop apps (Minecraft uses LWJGL).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. read through the discussion and it really seems to be whats happening to me. maybe ill try their patch that switches java2d with lwjgl and see how it goes. thanks again!